# Запуск bash скрипта .Net Core 2.2 C#

Tags: c#, linux, .net, bash, .net-core

Необходимо запустить скрипт написанный на Bash из программы написанной на C# .net core 2.2.

> cd /home/jman/myapp/
>
> ./test

В программе на С# сделал через запуск команд (хелпер):

```
 public string RunBashCommand(string cmd, Dictionary<string, string> environmentVariables = null)
    {
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                Arguments = $"-c \"{cmd}\"",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
            if (environmentVariables != null)
                foreach (var variable in environmentVariables)
                {
                    process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables[variable.Key] = variable.Value;
                }

            process.Start();
            var result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim('\n').Trim('\r');
            process.WaitForExit();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

И сам вызов:

```
 private void LoadDevice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(scriptRunner.RunBashCommand("cd /home/jman/myapp/"));
        Console.WriteLine(scriptRunner.RunBashCommand("./test"));
    }
```

Запускаю приложение написанное на C# в Ubuntu:

> dotnet MyCoreApp.dll

И получаю ошибку:

> /bin/bash: test: command not found

Собственно как правильно запустить скрипт?

Comment: Это же инициализация двух команд в разных сессиях получается? Попробуйте выполнить скрипт test с абсолютным путем, либо две команды подряд в рамках сессии `..("cd /home/jman/myapp/;./test"));`

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает! Можно было бы как ответ оформить, но может кто знает. как запустить именно сам скрипт, а не по командно.

Comment: запуск скрипта, если указать к нему абсолютный путь будет выглядеть так `...("/home/jman/myapp/test"))`

Comment: @PotroNik, а если я вызываю скрипт, который работает с устройством. `scriptRunner.RunBashCommand("cd /home/jman/myapp/;./test"` А потом при выходе из программы вызываю скрипт `scriptRunner.RunBashCommand("cd /home/jman/myapp/;./testunload"` То баш выдает ошибку: rmmod: ERROR: Module device is in use Это проблема о которой вы писали? Про разные сессии?

Comment: Похоже на то, что устройство занято к которому обращаетесь через sh, скрипт если напрямую запустить такой же результат высвечивает? Проблема с сессиями, которую я описывал, заключается в том, что на каждый вызов экземпляра создается отдельная сессия ssh, между которыми нет взаимодействия, т.е. все переменные переходы в каталоги и прочее в новом экземпляре не сохранятся.

Comment: @PotroNik если просто ручками запустить первый скрипт, потом второй, то проблем нет.

Comment: нет я только учусь и мне нужна помощь мастеров своего дела

Comment: @PotroNik да, вы были абсолютно правы. Я в коде занимал оборудование, поэтому при вызове второго скрипта летела ошибка.

Comment: Отлично, если не сложно ответьте на свой вопрос самостоятельно, как решили проблему с запуском и доступом к устройству.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, благодаря советам @PotroNik удалось запускать Bash скрипты.

Создан класс - хелпер:

```
public class BashShellHelper
{
    public string RunBashCommand(string cmd, Dictionary<string, string> environmentVariables = null)
    {
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                Arguments = $"-c \"{cmd}\"",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
            if (environmentVariables != null)
            {
                foreach (var variable in environmentVariables)
                {
                    process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables[variable.Key] = variable.Value;
                }
            }

            process.Start();
            var result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim('\n').Trim('\r');
            process.WaitForExit();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void RunBushScript(string cmd)
    {
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                Arguments = $"-c \"{cmd}\"",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }
}
```

в основной программе реализованы следующие методы:

```
  private readonly BashShellHelper scriptRunner =
        new BashShellHelper();
 private readonly loadDevScript = "cd /home/jman/myapp/;./test_load";
 private readonly unloadDevScript = "cd /home/jman/my_second_app/;./test_unload";

 public void LoadDevice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(scriptRunner.RunBashCommand($"{loadDevScript}"));
    }
```

И метод запускающий скрипт для выгрузки устройства:

```
public void UnloadDevice()
    {
        deviceManager.CloseDevice();
        Console.WriteLine(scriptRunner.RunBashCommand($"{unloadDevScript}"));
    }
```